# How to calculate next occurring date based on day of week from a start date?

Tags: postgresql

My events table has startdate and enddate columns.  It also has a recurring boolean column to flag as event as recurring.  I only need to support weekly recurrences.  How can I select the next appropriate date for these recurring events?

Given the following sample data and time of writing this, how can I get the following results?

```
startdate    enddate     nextdate
12/29/14     12/31/15    1/12/15
1/2/15       4/1/15      1/9/15
6/1/14       12/31/14    null
4/1/15       12/31/15    4/1/15
```

UPDATE: I just wrote this function but now I'm wondering if there isn't something more efficient...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION nextdowinrange(startdate timestamp with time zone, enddate timestamp with time zone)
  RETURNS timestamp with time zone AS
$BODY$
    DECLARE
        loopday int;
        nextdate timestamp with time zone;
        BEGIN

        --RANGE PAST
        IF enddate < current_timestamp THEN
            RETURN null;
        --RANGE NOT STARTED
        ELSIF startdate > current_timestamp THEN
            RETURN startdate;
        --SAME DAY OF WEEK
        ELSIF extract(dow from startdate) = extract(dow from current_timestamp) THEN
            RETURN startdate;
        --FIND NEXT
        ELSE
            loopday:= 0;
            LOOP
                IF extract(dow from now() + (loopday || ' days')::interval) = extract(dow from startdate) THEN
                    nextdate:= now() + (loopday || ' days')::interval;
                END IF;
                EXIT WHEN extract(dow from now() + (loopday || ' days')::interval) = extract(dow from startdate);
                loopday:= loopday + 1;

            END LOOP;
            RETURN nextdate;
        END IF;

        END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with simple selects, there is no need for a custom function.

The simplest solution for PostgreSQL 9.3+ is a [`LATERAL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) join:

```
select  t.*, nextdate
from    t
left join lateral (
  select nextdate
  from   generate_series(startdate, enddate, '1 week') nextdate
  where  nextdate > now()
  limit  1
) nd on true;
```

For older PostgreSQL, you can use sub-select for the `nextdate` column:

```
select *, (select ds
           from   generate_series(startdate, enddate, '1 week') ds
           where  ds > now()
           limit  1) nextdate
from   t;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/77ff8/12)

Comment: Nice :-) Just a question - your limit statement on the lateral subquery; is there a potential issue in the order? Does that guarantee that you'll get the earliest date?

Comment: @mlinth `generate_series` always returns an ordered result set. PostgreSQL won't re-order function result sets, unless it's explicitly told to do so. Unfortunately there is not much documentation of this feature, I could only find this: *If `ORDER BY` is not given, the rows are returned in whatever order the system finds fastest to produce.* http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html

Answer (score 0):

The query below will give you what you want. Hopefully that gives you the basic idea and you can modify to suit your needs.

I took the liberty of adding an id column (makes the joins easier), and I assume startdate and enddate are of type `date`:

```
alter table mydates add date_id serial primary key
```

Let me explain the query: The inside query generates a series of dates. The next query gets the earliest future date in that series (for each id) - this will not return a record for rows where enddate is in the past. Therefore there's an outer query that adds those missing records with a null nextdate.

```
SELECT a.startdate,a.enddate,nextdate FROM -- outer query with left join to get finished ranges
    mydates a
LEFT JOIN 
         -- select the earliest date in the future from the series
         -- This will not contain rows where the enddate is in the past
    (SELECT date_id,min(theweeks)::date AS nextdate FROM 
        (SELECT date_id, generate_series -- Get a series of the week dates
           (
           startdate
           ,enddate
           , '1 week'::interval) as theweeks 
         FROM mydates
         ) AS daterange
    WHERE now() < theweeks
    GROUP BY date_id) AS nextdates
ON nextdates.date_id = a.date_id
ORDER BY a.date_id
```