# Get records after a certain time in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id | flight_number | departure_time | arrival_time
---+---------------+----------------+-------------
 1 | UAL123        | 07:00:00       | 08:30:00
---+---------------+----------------+-------------
 2 | AAL456        | 07:30:00       | 08:40:00
---+---------------+----------------+-------------
 3 | SWA789        | 07:45:00       | 09:10:00
```

I'm trying to figure out an SQL query that can get upcoming flights based on departure time given the current time. For instance, at `07:20`, I would like to return `AAL456, SWA789` since those flights have not departed yet. At `07:40`, I would like to just return `SWA789`. What is a good way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27834235/how-to-calculate-next-occurring-date-based-on-day-of-week-from-a-start-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use `LOCALTIME` to get the current time.  So, if the `departure_time` is stored as a `time`, then:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.departure_time > localtime;
```

This assumes no time zone information is part of the time value.  Also, it will return no flights after the last flight has departed for a day (which is consistent with the phrasing of your question).

Comment: The column was created as `time(0) without time zone`, but when I run this query it's still returning all rows.

Comment: @AndrewDeForest . . . Perhaps you should check the `localtime` on the system you are using.

Comment: good call...didn't work on my development machine but worked on the production server.